# How to intercept the logs Log.d/w/e via Listener

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-logcat, android-log

After search a lot in the stackoverflow and via google about how to intercept the logs in my application. The solution that I found is executing the command `logcat -v time` in the runtime but this solution print all the logs and I just want to intercept all the calls to the Log.d/w/e methods inside my application.

**Question**

> Is there some solution like attaching a listener to one class that
>   report me all the logs?

**For example**

> Get the Logger.getGlobal() and add some handler or listener to the
>   main logger to receive all the logs.

Any information about this would be great!

Comment: AspectJ might do what you want. I'm afraid I haven't used it so can't offer any examples or provide a link. :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to replace the standard Log in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736320/is-there-a-way-to-replace-the-standard-log-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

> The solution that I found is executing the command logcat -v time

That is not documented and not supported.

> Is there some solution like attaching a listener to one class that report me all the logs?

Only if you use your own logging wrapper. There are [various libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/57) available that give you more flexible logging options.

Comment: You can execute "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time");" for example. My problem is is that I can't use a logging wrapper because the application fully coupled with the Log.d/e/w. Thanks!!

Comment: Well, if you're on linux, you could do a find/replace through all the files and point to your wrapper instead (not sure about the windows variant, though), e.g.: grep -rl 'android.utils.Logger' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/android.utils.Logger/com.myapp.utils.Logger/g'    where you replace com.myapp.utils.Logger with your Logger wrapper class, that just mimics the same calls to Log.d/e/w and can trigger some callback